# Drag and drop a div in Drupal 7

Tags: jquery, drupal, drag-and-drop

I am trying to use drag and drop of a div (using jQuery) in Drupal 7.   I am using jQuery 1.4.4 and jQuery-ui 1.8.7.   The code works in a simple html file.   I see the inclusion of the 1.4.4 jQuery file in the standard Drupal 7 setup.   I am making a specific include of query-ui 1.8.7 because I am seeing no include of the jquery-ui.  When I embed the following code in a Drupal 7 basic page, it does not work ...

```
<style>
    .draggable { width: 10px; height: 10px; float: left; margin: 0px; 
                 background: gold ; border: 0px solid gold ; border: 1px solid black ; }
    #draggable { cursor: e-resize; width: 800px ; height: 70px ; 
                 background: blue ; border: 1px solid black ; }
    #containment-wrapper { width: 800px; height:144px; border:2px solid #ccc; 
                 background: gold ;}
</style>

<div id-containment-wrapper">
    <div id="draggable" class="draggable ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ axis: "x" });
    });     
</script>
```

Why would this not work? Nothing drags. I am attempting to create a draggable div that constrains the drag to the horizontal direction.

Please, suggestions would be appreciated ...

Thank you
   Dave

Comment: Try adding `drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.draggable');` into a PHP script somewhere in your page build (e.g. `hook_preprocess_page()` in your theme's template.php file)

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the solution.